# Problem with loading saved polygon in google map drawingManager Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hello everybody first time asking here. I'll be short, I made a custom pop up with loaded google map with option so the user can draw a Polygon , then the coordinates are saved along with the custom colors of fill and opacity etc. set by user. But when reload the pop up all coordinates and custom set colors etc. Are shown but the "Shape" is not loaded. I wish I could make it appear so user wont be confused. I'm quite new to coding so my knowledge is limited. I give you the code example. In the TS You will notice that I try to push the saved coordinates in **const points = []**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<br />
<div *ngIf="pointList && pointList.length>0" class="display-flex">
    <button (click)="deleteSelectedShape()">Clear</button>
</div>
<div style="overflow: auto">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-list>
                <li *ngFor="let point of pointList">
                    lat - {{ point.lat.toPrecision(5) }} ,
                    lng - {{ point.lng.toPrecision(5) }}
                </li>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-item class="comp-card ion-margin-bottom">
                <ion-label position="floating">Fill Color (HEX)</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="fillColor" (ionChange)="updateShape()"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="comp-card ion-margin-bottom">
                <ion-label position="floating">Fill Opacity (0 - 1)</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="fillOpacity" (ionChange)="updateShape()"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="comp-card ion-margin-bottom">
                <ion-label position="floating">Stroke Color (HEX)</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="strokeColor" (ionChange)="updateShape()"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="comp-card ion-margin-bottom">
                <ion-label position="floating">Stroke Weight (px)</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="strokeWeight" (ionChange)="updateShape()"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="comp-card ion-margin-bottom">
                <ion-label position="floating">Stroke Opacity (0 - 1)</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="strokeOpacity" (ionChange)="updateShape()"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-button (click)="setCoords()" >save</ion-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</div>
```

Type Script

```
import { PageComponentSettings } from '../../../models/page-component-settings/page-component-settings';
import { MapLoaderService } from './map-loader';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

declare var google: any;
var drawingManager;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-draw',
  templateUrl: './map-draw.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-draw.component.scss'],
})

export class MapDrawComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() mapCenter: {};
  map: any;
  drawingManager: any;
  coords: any;
  selectedShape: any;
  selectedArea = 0;
  @Input() pointList: { lat: number; lng: number }[] = [];
  @Input() fillColor = '#000000';
  @Input() fillOpacity = '1';
  @Input() strokeColor = '#000000';
  @Input() strokeOpacity = '1';
  @Input() strokeWeight = '1';

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private modalControler: ModalController,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    MapLoaderService.load().then(() => {
      this.initDrawingManager();
    })
  }

  initDrawingManager(){


    const points = [];

    for(let point of this.pointList) {
      points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng));
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: this.mapCenter,
      zoom: 14,
    }); 
    const self = this;
    const options = {
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: ['polygon'],
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      },
      polygonOptions: {
        strokeColor: this.strokeColor,
        strokeWeight: this.strokeWeight,
        fillColor: this.fillColor,
        fillOpacity: this.fillOpacity,
        path: points
      }
    };
    this.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager(options);
    this.drawingManager.setMap(this.map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(
      this.drawingManager,
      'overlaycomplete',
      (event) => {
        if (event.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
          const paths = event.overlay.getPaths();
          for (let p = 0; p < paths.getLength(); p++) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(
              paths.getAt(p),
              'set_at',
              () => {
                if (!event.overlay.drag) {
                  self.updatePointList(event.overlay.getPath());
                }
              }
            );
            google.maps.event.addListener(
              paths.getAt(p),
              'insert_at',
              () => {
                self.updatePointList(event.overlay.getPath());
              }
            );
            google.maps.event.addListener(
              paths.getAt(p),
              'remove_at',
              () => {
                self.updatePointList(event.overlay.getPath());
              }
            );
          }
          self.updatePointList(event.overlay.getPath());
          this.selectedShape = event.overlay;

          this.selectedShape.type = event.type;
          console.log(this.pointList);
        }
        // Saving Coordinates
        this.coords = JSON.stringify(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
        console.log(this.coords)

        if (event.type !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
          // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
          self.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
          // To hide:
          self.drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingControl: false,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }

  deleteSelectedShape() {
    if (this.selectedShape) {
      this.selectedShape.setMap(null);
      this.selectedArea = 0;
      this.pointList = [];
      // To show:
      this.drawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingControl: true,
      });
    }
  }

  updatePointList(path) {
    this.pointList = [];
    const len = path.getLength();
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      this.pointList.push(
        path.getAt(i).toJSON()
      );
    }
  }

  updateShape() {
    this.selectedShape.set('strokeColor', this.strokeColor);
    this.selectedShape.set('fillColor', this.fillColor);
    this.selectedShape.set('strokeWeight', this.strokeWeight);
    this.selectedShape.set('fillOpacity', this.fillOpacity);
    this.selectedShape.set('strokeOpacity', this.strokeOpacity);
  }

  setCoords(){
    return this.modalControler.dismiss({
      isSet: true,
      coords: this.coords,
      fillColor: this.fillColor,
      fillOpacity: this.fillOpacity,
      strokeOpacity: this.strokeOpacity,
      strokeColor: this.strokeColor,
      strokeWeight: this.strokeWeight,
    });  
  }
}
```

TS for mapLoader

```
export class MapLoaderService {
    private static promise: Promise<any>;
    public static load(): Promise<any> {
      let browserKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
      let map = {
        URL: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,drawing&key=' + browserKey + '&callback=__onGoogleLoaded',     
      }
  
      // First time 'load' is called?
      if (!this.promise) {
  
        // Make promise to load
        this.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
          this.loadScript(map.URL);        
          // Set callback for when google maps is loaded.
          window['__onGoogleLoaded'] = ($event) => {
            resolve('google maps api loaded');
          };
        })
      }
  
      // Always return promise. When 'load' is called many times, the promise is already resolved.
      return this.promise;
    }
  
    //this function will work cross-browser for loading scripts asynchronously
    static loadScript(src, callback?): void {
      var s: any,
        r,
        t;
      r = false;
      s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = src;
      s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //console.log( this.readyState ); //uncomment this line to see which ready states are called.
        if (!r && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
          r = true;
          if (typeof callback === "function")
            callback();
        }
      };
      t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
    }
  }
```